# Can't open cygwin terminal after installation

Tags: cygwin

I just installed cygwin in my **windows7** pc. After installation when i click on **'Cygwin Terminal'** from start menu it shows a message like this - message title: **Missing Shortcut** "Windows is searching for **mintty**. To locate the file yourself, click Browse" with two buttons below **"Browse"** and **"Cancel"**.
Then if I select **mintty.exe** manually from "C:\cygwin\bin" by clicking **Browse** button it doesn't load anything. How can I be get rid of this?

Comment: I had the same problem. Said mintty was installed, but there was no mintty.exe in bin. I had to re-install, downloading from a different mirror.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Open the Cygwin Terminal properties (by right click on the icon and go to properties) check the path of 'mintty'. If everything looks right and it is still giving error, change the 'mintty' to 'mintty.exe'. This solved my problem.

Comment: Worked perfectly! This solution is much hackier than should be necessary with a normal installation... I'm curious as to why or how long this has been happening.

Comment: The problem is why the Cygwin team use *mintty* instead of *mintty.exe*? is it a bug?

Comment: @cinqS, Yeah probably. But I have stopped using Cygwin now. We can use Windows Subsystem for Linux (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide) which is pretty cool.

Comment: @RChat, sure, that must be cool... but not possible for those who are using Win7 or behind a enterprise update plan. So Cygwin is still a need.

Answer (score 4):

For Installing Cygwin follow the steps given here-

-Link is now dead-
http://www.news.amigowork.com/how-to-install-unix-in-windows/

if problem is still there

then

go to installation directory and open Cygwin.bat

or

go to bin folder of installation directory and open mintty.exe.

it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Cygwin Terminal properties (by right click on the icon and go to properties) check the path of 'mintty'. If it is not as per your minty(you will get it inside bin folder) location change it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed cygwin in e drive. But the path (in property, by right click on icon )showed c drive.  When i changed it to e, the problem went away. It was on Windows 7 and cygwin installation was latest on 4th Jan 2018.